# How does sourceforge start the javascript based download?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, download, popup

Trying to do something similiar to how sourceforge starts the download on the page, and uses a direct link in case it doesn't work.

I can't seem to locate the javascript they use to start the downlaod popup.

Exampe link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlparser/files/Integration-Builds/2.0-20060923/HTMLParser-2.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip/download

Answer (score 1):

If you view source of the download page you refer to in the question there is a javascript include:

```
<script src="http://a.fsdn.com/con/js/download.js?1270839227" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This script do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a simple `meta redirect` to the download url?
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://domain.com/download">`